# Full text sql server strange results

Tags: sql-server-2014, full-text-search

I have 2 documents let's say A ( word document) and b ( pdf version ) stored as blob and full text search enabled.

I have 2 words which are present in both documents. Searching for the first word with the contains operator returns both documents. Search for the second only returns one of them.

I also queried the database to list both search terms and the documents indexed for each ( a sql server system procedure that lists all documents for each search term) and to my suprise both documents show up even with the correct number of occurences in each document.

So why would contains not return all results even if the seem to be in the full text index.

Keyword (binary form) and search_term match exacty for both documents

Comment: Have you opened both documents with for example Notepad.exe and tried to find if this words are presents inside the document in plain text, I mean no special characters?

Comment: I compared the Keyword value ( which is the unicode byte array ) stored in the index and the are for both documents exactly the same ( as well as the display_term which is the textual version of the Keyword also compares  as the same ).